# Find documents from a multiple selector element in MongoDB and Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How would you guys do this: I've got a multiple html selector like this

```
<select multiple id="ss-week">
    <option value="" disabled selected>SS Week</option>
    <option value="Week1">Week 1</option>
    <option value="Week2">Week 2</option>
    <option value="Week3">Week 3</option>
    <option value="Week4">Week 4</option>
    <option value="Week5">Week 5</option>
    <option value="Week6">Week 6</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" id="ss-week-button">GO</button>
```

If the user selects Week 1 and Week 2 and clicks the button, the query would need to find those documents where the field values of 'Week1' and 'Week2' would be "1" with the other weeks (Week3 thru Week6) equal to "0". I've got some jQuery that puts the selections into an array:

```
Template.clientQuery.events({
  'click #ss-week-button': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedValues = [];
    $("#ss-week option:selected").each(function(){
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
    //more code...
});
```

In our example, the selectedValues = ["Week1", "Week2"]. Now for the Mongo query. What it would need to do in principle would be:

```
Programs.find({ Week1: "1", Week2: "1", Week3: "0", Week4: "0", Week5: "0", Week6: "0" });
```

So, based on the user's selection of weeks, we'd need 1's in the appropriate spots in the mongo query. How to do this?

All of the Weeks fields (Week1 thru Week6) contain strings "1" or "0".

Answer (score 0):

I answered my problem. It involved a few for-loops to create the proper array of 1's and 0's. Starting from the beginning and creating an array of selected values from the selector:

```
var selectedValues = [];
  $("#ss-week option:selected").each(function(){
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Parse them into integers, create a "Zero" array and splice 1's into the proper position:

```
var zeroArray = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
var ints = [];
for (var i = 1, len = selectedValues.length; i < len; i++)
   ints.push(parseInt(selectedValues[i]));

for (var j = 0, leng = ints.length; j < leng; j++)
  zeroArray.splice(ints[j] - 1, 1, 1);
```

Then turn all values back into strings:

```
var final = [];
for (var k = 0, leng = zeroArray.length; k < leng; k++) {
  if (typeof zeroArray[k] === "number")
    final.push((zeroArray[k]).toString());
  else
    final.push(zeroArray[k]);
}
```

This will result in an array of strings such that if the user selected Week 1, Week 3, and Week 5, the array would be:

```
 ["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]
```

Then the Mongo Query:

```
Programs.find({ Week1: final[0], Week2: final[1], Week3: final[2]... Week6: final[5] });
```